# Let $|G|=pqr$, where $p$, $q$ and $r$ are primes with $p<q<r$. Then $G$ has a normal $Syl_p$ AND a normal $Syl_q$ AND a normal $Syl_r$ subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, sylow-theory

**Claim**: Let $|G|=pqr$, where $p$, $q$ and $r$ are primes with $p<q<r$. Then $G$ has a normal $Syl_p$ AND a normal $Syl_q$ AND a normal $Syl_r$ subgroup.

**Proof**: It can be proven that $G$ has a normal Sylow subgroup for either $p$, $q$ or $r$.

Case I: Suppose $Syl_p\lhd G$; then $\overline{G}:=G/Syl_p$ is a group. and $|\overline{G}|=|G/Syl_p|=|G|/|Syl_p|=pqr/p=qr$. Thus $\overline{G}$ contains a normal Sylow $r$-subgroup by the classification of groups of order equaling a product of two distinct primes-call it $\overline{Syl_r}$. By *The Fourth Isomorphism Theorem*, there must exist a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $r$, which is a Sylow $r$-subgroup in $G$-call it $Syl_r$.

Apply the above argument to $Syl_r$ yields another normal Sylow subgroup in $G$, namely $Syl_q$.

Case II: Suppose $Syl_q\lhd G$. See Case I.

Case III: Suppose $Syl_r\lhd G$. See Case I.

**Q.E.D**.

**My Question**: Something doesn't feel right in this proof; but I couldn't tell what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The claim is wrong. It would imply all such groups are abelian. To see where things are wrong, try to apply it to $S_3\times C_5$, of order $2\times 3\times 5$, which does not have a normal Sylow 2-subgroup.

Comment: You are misapplying the isomorphism Theorems. If $G/P$ has a normal subgroup of order $q$, this means that $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $q|P|$ containing $P$. You do not get from this a normal subgroup of order $q$, though. In my example that happens if you mod out by the normal subgroup of order $3$.

Comment: Also, even if you had a normal $r$ subgroup and a normal $q$ subgroup, applying the same argument again to the $q$ subgroup would just give you back the $r$-subgroup. You never get a normal,$p$ subgroup. So your "See Case I" would be invalid in the other two cases anyway.